# Can we have one .exe calling a .dll with XAML and Prism (for MVVM)?

Tags: prism

My question is this: How can I call a library project (DLL) that contains all my XAML (Views) and ViewModel classes from another project that is meant to only run as an "EXE"? (I want to use Prism 7 for MVVM purposes).

My intent is to have one project whose only purpose is to create an .EXE. This EXE will load the assembly where the actual WPF views and the viewmodels reside.

Ideally, I'd like to have App.xaml in the EXE project... But I want to have my Bootstrapper in the Assembly project... Is this possible with Prism 7?

I want to have an App.xaml in "Company.Product.Application" project (which produces an EXE):

```
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Company.Product.Application"
         xmlns:Presentation="clr-namespace:Company.Product.Presentation;assembly=Product.Presentation"
         DispatcherUnhandledException="Application_DispatcherUnhandledException"
         xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/">
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Presentation:AppBootstrapper x:Key="Bootstrapper" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then from my Bootstrapper, I want to load my IoC and create my views and viewmodels.

I have been able to accomplish this with Caliburn.Micro... The idea here is that  "Company.Product.Presentation" DLL can be tested out without having to create an EXE in itself. I could add the reference to "Presentation" in my test project (NUnit) and test it independently. The EXE is just a project that calls on "Company.Product.Presentation" DLL to actually generate Graphical User Interface goodness.

I appreciate any insight you may have in regards to this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> But I want to have my Bootstrapper in the Assembly project... Is this possible with Prism 7?

Sure, just reference the dll with the bootstrapper from the exe and put something like this in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
protected override void Onstartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    var bootstrapper = new Company.Product.Presentation.Bootstrapper();
    bootstrapper.Run();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Haukinger. That was indeed very helpful!

Comment: One quick question... Is there a way to completely remove the code behind (MyView.xaml.cs)  such that I only end up with the MyView.xaml file? In Caliburn.Micro, I can completely remove the code behind. What I observe in Prism is that if I do not leave the constructor (with its InitializeComponent method) alone, then things don't bind. It is a minor thing, but ideally, I would want my team to not even see code behind in the view files. Thanks again!

Comment: You do not need to use a `UserControl` for your view, you can use a custom control, too. But I personally just remove everything from code-behind but the constructor calling `InitializeComponent` and forget about it...